# NativeBase: Generate Columns in Row

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I want to map a number of items in an array to a grid of 3 columns for each row. Right now I have the entire grid hardcoded, but it should be trivial to do this automatically.

This is what the end result should look like:

```
<Grid>  
  <Col> 
    <Row>Cel 1</Row>
    <Row>Cel 2</Row>
    <Row>Cel 3</Row>
  </Col>
  <Col> 
    <Row>Cel 4</Row>
    <Row>Cel 5</Row>
    <Row>Cel 6</Row>
  </Col>
  <Col> 
    <Row>Cel 4</Row>
    <Row>Cel 5</Row>
    <Row>Cel 6</Row>
  </Col>
  <Col> 
    <Row>Cel 4</Row>
    <Row>Cel 5</Row>
    <Row>Cel 6</Row>
  </Col>
  <Col> 
    <Row>Cel 4</Row>
    <Row>Cel 5</Row>
    <Row>Cel 6</Row>
  </Col>          
</Grid>
```

Here is the render method, which does not do much atm. Im not sure how to even start on this issue.

```
render() {
    let images = [
      Images.grid1,
      Images.grid2,
      Images.grid3,
      Images.grid4,
      Images.grid5,
      Images.grid6,
      Images.grid7,
      Images.grid8,
      Images.grid9
    ];

return images.map(link => {
    return (
      <Grid>
       <Row>
        <Col>link</Col>
        <Col>link</Col>
        <Col>link</Col>
       </Row>
       <Row>
        <Col>link</Col>
        <Col>link</Col>
        <Col>link</Col>
       </Row>
      </Grid> 
      );
   });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your images array should be stored in `state` or `props` whenever possible because when your images get updated(insert, remove or delete), `React` will re`render` your component again.

And your Images array should be re-structured as an example below in order to render with three column in each row.

```
gridArray = [
    [image1, image2, image3],
    [image4, image5, image6],
    [image7, image8, image9],
];
```

Take a look at my working example on CodeSandbox through this link https://codesandbox.io/s/jly9332lzy.

In the example on CodeSandbox I change the component from `Grid` to `div`, `Row` to `ul` and `Col` to `li` to avoid errors on the online sandbox. You just change components to `Grid`, `Row` and `Col`, edit code a bit to adapt to your code and everything will work.

Below is my code that solves your problems

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Your source data
    this.state = {
      images: [
        "Image 1",
        "Image 2",
        "Image 3",
        "Image 4",
        "Image 5",
        "Image 6",
        "Image 7",
        "Image 8",
        "Image 9",
      ]
    };
  }

  // this method will return structured array like this.
  // gridArray = [
  //    [image1, image2, image3],
  //    [image4, image5, image6],
  //    [image7, image8, image9],
  // ];
  imagesArrayToGridArray(totalColumns) {
    let gridArray = [[]];

    let countColumns = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.images.length; i++) {
      gridArray[gridArray.length - 1].push(this.state.images[i]);
      if (countColumns <= totalColumns) {
        countColumns++;
      }
      if (countColumns > totalColumns && i !== this.state.images.length - 1) {
        countColumns = 1;
        gridArray.push([]);
      }
    }

    return gridArray;
  }

  // return React Components like
  // <Row>
  //   <Col>Image 1</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 2</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 3</Col>
  // </Row>
  // <Row>
  //   <Col>Image 4</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 5</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 6</Col>
  // </Row>
  // <Row>
  //   <Col>Image 7</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 8</Col>
  //   <Col>Image 9</Col>
  // </Row>
  renderGrid(gridArray) {
    return gridArray.map(row => (
      <Row>{row.map(col => (<Col>{col}</Col>))}</Row>
    ));
  }

  // render
  render() {
    let gridArray = this.imagesArrayToGridArray(3);
    return <Grid>{this.renderGrid(gridArray)}</Grid>;
  }
}

render(<YourComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And that's it, now everything will work.

Comment: No props. It was my pleasure.