# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, jsx

Facing an issue while rendering view. Trying to populate a two dimensional array in JSX.

Sample Code:

```
export default class ItemListScreen extends Component {

    imagesArrayToGridArray(totalColumns) {
        const albums = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'wahid'
                },

                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'sayem'
                },

                {
                    id: 3,
                    name: 'amanot'
                },

                {
                    id: 4,
                    name: 'shimul'
                }
            ]
        let gridArray = [[]];

        let countColumns = 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
            gridArray[gridArray.length - 1].push(albums[i])
            if (countColumns <= totalColumns) {
            countColumns++;
        }
        if (countColumns > totalColumns && i !== albums.length - 1) {
            countColumns = 1
            gridArray.push([])
        }

        return gridArray
    }

    renderGrid(gridArray) {
        return gridArray.map(row => (
          <Row>{row.map(col => console.log({col}))}</Row>
        ))
    }

    renderView() {
        let gridArray = this.imagesArrayToGridArray(2)
        return <Grid>{this.renderGrid(gridArray)}</Grid>
    }

    render() {
        const { contents } = styles;
        return (
                    {
                        this.renderView()
                    } 
        );
    }
}
```

It gives following error in metro bundler:

> (node:3956) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: E:/projects/NewProject/app/screens/ItemListScreen.js: Unexpected token, expected ; (60:26)

[image]

I want to arrange the array as a two D array:

```
<Row>
  <Col>Wahid</Col>
  <Col>Sayem<Col>
</Row>
<Row>
  <Col>Amanot</Col>
  <Col>Shimul<Col>
</Row>
```

Have got the idea from below link. But still facing issue while trying to implement:
[NativeBase: Generate Columns in Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48029078/nativebase-generate-columns-in-row)

Comment: it looks like you are missing one `}` on line `60`

Comment: no, i have checked :(

Comment: Add function before the function's name 
also you need to add another curly bracket in order to close imagesArrayToGridArray

Comment: @BasilBattikhi It's probably part of a `class` body - people *always* forget to post that

Comment: He didn't mentioned that it's part of class and we shouldn't expect the happy scenario so that i guess they are not of part of class and if so  
he needs to add a close curly bracket above renderGrid Function

Comment: I Strongly Recomended to install Eslint plugin for javascript developers

Comment: @BasilBattikhi thanks, my bad it was closing } problem. I will use eslint from now on.

Comment: As as i mentiond above there was missing close curly bracket